# Help on understanding this congruency

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences

It is really simple but somehow I cannot connect the dots.

If $p$ is an odd prime, how come $-1 \not\equiv 1 \pmod p$  ?

Comment: Go back to th definition of congruency.

Comment: Forget the prime, when `-1 = 1 (mod n)`?

Answer (score 2):

because if $p$ is an odd prime then it has the form of $p = 2k+1$ for some positive integer $k$ and $-1 \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ requires that $n \mid -1 -1=-2$

because $$a \equiv b \pmod n \iff n \mid a -b$$
however, $p = 2k+1$ and surely, $2k + 1 \not \mid -2$ because no odd number greater than 1 divides $2$ or $-2$ and so $-1 \not\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$

Generally , if $p > 2$ it will work also.

Comment: just corrected it

Comment: Why does "need $p$ to be an odd prime"?  The incongruence holds for any number larger than $2$.  $p=4$ works fine.

Comment: u are right @ErickWong

Comment: thanks for the kind answer. I posted the answer and thought about it second and realize a odd prime can't divide -2. really appreciate!

Comment: U are welcome @WrenNam, Try not to rush to ask questions, Try to think for a long time first. That's real mathematics